# Помогите написать SQL запрос с использованием арифметических функций

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `user_balance (id, user_id, status, count, comment, add_date)`. Необходимо написать функцию, которая будет делать следующую операцию:

```
*1: считаем операции со status = 1*
*2: считаем операции со status = 2*
*вычитаем из результата 2 операции результат 1*
*передаем данные на бэкэнд*
```

Пока что не могу разобраться со вложенными запросами :(

---

Извиняюсь, немного неправильно построил вопрос. Нужно посчитать значения столбца count. Т.е. вот так:

```
*1: считаем столбец count из строк, где операции со status = 1*
*2: считаем столбец count из строк, где операции со status = 2*
*вычитаем из результата 2 операции результат 1*
*передаем данные на бэкэнд*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status= 2
        )
        -
        (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status = 1
        )
) AS result
```

---

После обновления вопроса нужно это чтоль?

```
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(`count`)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status= 2
        )
        -
        (SELECT SUM(`count`)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status = 1
        )
) AS result
```

Comment: изменил вопрос, немного неправильно написал

Comment: @Alexxosipov ну замени `COUNT(1)` на `COUNT(\`count\`)` разницы все равно не будет. или тебе сумма из count Нужна в каждом запросе?

Comment: мне нужна сумма из count именно) это запрос на вычисление суммы баланса

Comment: да, все работает, спасибо огромное)

Comment: @Alexxosipov ну замени `COUNT(\`count\`)` на `SUM(\`count\`)` :D

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без вложенных запросов:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status=1, 1, 0)) - SUM(IF(status=2, 1, 0))
FROM `user_balance`
WHERE status IN (1,2);
```

Comment: изменил вопрос, немного неправильно написал